# JMeter : What is idle time in table listener?

Tags: jmeter

[image: Table Listener Report]

What does `IdleTime` represent in a JMeter report as exemplified above?

Answer (score 2):

Idle time is time wasted between your operations/samplers.

Add your samplers under [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller),

Remain check box "Include duration of timer and pre-post processors in generated sample" **unchecked**

It will add idle time which it's the time the controller "wasted"

Answer (score 1):

```
Idle Time = time not spent sampling (milliseconds) (generally 0)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.